# iOS Continuous Integration with Jenkins, Hockey, and increase version

Tags: ios, jenkins, hockeyapp, fastlane

Currently, I am using Jenkins, fastlane and Hockey to do UITesting and deliver application to end users. I have set up in Jenkins to automatically upload ipa file to hockey.

I need to upload to hockey daily and I can run script for that. But how can I increase version every time when I upload to hockey?

Also, to be safe, I don't want to store that version number in local file or something. Instead, I want to retrieve version number from hockey and increase based on that number. Is there anyway to implement that one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use fastlane's [`increment_build_number`](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/docs/Actions.md#increment_build_number) action for this.

Comment: Is it also okay for hockey?

Comment: HockeyApp just shows the build number that is in your app package. Just increase the build number of your app and everything will work.